# toDataURL is not a function in ios

Tags: javascript, ios, html5-canvas, onload, todataurl

To get a data URL containing image data of a snapshot of the canvas I'm using toDataURL function in my application which works fine in browsers(including safari) and anroid devices but not working in iphone/ipad(on any browser).

It's throwing me a type error img.toDataURL is not a function. When I'm trying to load the image explicitly the function never triggers in iphone/ipad.

Here is my code snippet

```
_drawImage(img) {
        // console.log("drawimage");
        this.setState({ isGenerating: true });
        if (img) {
            fetch(img)
                .then((r) => r.blob())
                .then((blob) => {
                    loadImage(
                        blob,
                        (img) => {
                            if (img.type === "error") {
                                this.setState({ error: true });
                                // console.log(img, "Error loading image ");
                            } else {
                                const image = new window.Image();
                                const height = this.props.height;
                                const width = this.props.width;
                                console.log(img.height, img.width)
                                // image.src = img.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
                                if(image.complete){
                                    let offsetX,
                                        offsetY,
                                        renderableWidth = image.width,
                                        renderableHeight = image.height;
                                    console.log(image.width, image.height)
                                    var imageDimensionRatio = image.width / image.height;
                                    var canvasDimensionRatio = width / height;
                                    console.log(
                                      "ratios of image and canvas =",
                                      imageDimensionRatio,
                                      canvasDimensionRatio
                                    );
                                    if (imageDimensionRatio < canvasDimensionRatio) {
                                        renderableHeight = height;
                                        renderableWidth =
                                            image.width * (renderableHeight / image.height);
                                        offsetX = (width - renderableWidth) / 2;
                                        offsetY = 0;
                                    } else if (imageDimensionRatio > canvasDimensionRatio) {
                                        renderableWidth = width;
                                        renderableHeight =
                                            image.height * (renderableWidth / image.width);
                                        offsetX = 0;
                                        offsetY = (height - renderableHeight) / 2;
                                    } else {
                                        renderableHeight = height;
                                        renderableWidth = width;
                                        offsetX = 0;
                                        offsetY = 0;
                                    }
                                    console.log(renderableHeight, renderableWidth)
                                    this.setState(
                                        {
                                            image: image,
                                            renderableHeight,
                                            renderableWidth,
                                            imgHeight: image.height,
                                            imgWidth: image.width,
                                            offsetX,
                                            offsetY,
                                            height,
                                            width,
                                        },
                                        () => {
                                            this.setState({ isGenerating: false });
                                        }
                                    );
                                }
                                
                                image.src = img.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            orientation: true,
                            canvas: true,
                        }
                    );
                });
        }
    }
```

Comment: A HTML Image doesn't have a `toDataURL` so I'm surprised its working in any browser.  Did you try Firefox as that's often more strict.   Normally you would either 1, render to a canvas and use it's `toDataURL` or seen as you appear to have a blob use a `FileReader.readAsDataURL `..

Comment: Thanks for the comment and yes I've tried this in firefox and it works but the underlying issue of my problem is something else I guess. As I'm trying to render the canvas using it's toDataURL but the image dimmensions are exceeding the ipad limit of sorts so it refuses everytime I try to render the canvas.
Basically my problem is quite similar to this one [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456071/ipad-iphone-error-on-preloading-image)

Comment: What's `loadImage`?

Comment: `loadImage` is a function provided by an external library `blueimp-load-image`.

Comment: It returns an image tag with its src.

Comment: So that's not a canvas, it doesn't have a `toDataURL()` method.

Comment: Actually, toDataURL converts the img canvas to base64 but the issue was that ios has a limit for image width which was exceeding in my case. However I've solved it by setting `maxWidth` in the options to `loadImage` function. So know the image.onload is working on ios device too.
Thanks for the response nonetheless.